# Knockout.js: ViewModel Properties not observed

Tags: knockout.js, mapping, angular2-observables

I think I am missing a fundamental concept somewhere.
The output on the code below is 100%, but the properties on the object isn't "observed".

```
<script>
    var model = { };

    var mapping = {            
            create: function () {
                var _profile;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'Manage.aspx/GetContact',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (results) {
                        _profile = results.d;
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
                    }
                });
                return _profile;
            }
    };      

    $(document).ready(function () {                        
        var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mapping);
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
</script>

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
    <label>E-Mail:</label></dt>
        <dd><span data-bind="text: E_Mail" /></dd>
        <dd><asp:TextBox runat="server" data-bind="value: E_Mail" /></dd>
</dl>
```

My code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static DynamicsNAV.NavContact.Contact GetContact()
{
    DynamicsNAV.NavContact.Contact contact = ReadContact();
    if(contact == null)
    {
        contact = new DynamicsNAV.NavContact.Contact();
        contact.E_Mail = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }

    return contact;
}
```

In this sample, I try to see if the UI is updated when changing the e-mail address in the textbox, which it doesn't.
If I add an email: ko.observable(); property to the model, and use it in the textbox and label, the update works as expected.

If I do:

```
var model = ko.observable();
```

No values are displayed when page is loaded. And no errors are raised.

Kind Regards,
EV

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem you describe but couldn't. Could you check out this fiddle and see if it represents what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/wgcdeyyf/

Comment: Can you use actual rendered HTML for your server-side control and come up with a jsfiddle replication of the issue (just stub the service response)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the replies, it did send my thinking process on a path to solve my problem!

My issue appeared to have been in the mapping and the sequence of processing.
In general, I misunderstood the function of 'create' in the mapping.
I thought it could assist with retrieval and populating the model.

So this ended up being my solution:

- Populate data
- Map it to view model

  ```
  var model = { };

  var vm;
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'Manage.aspx/GetContact',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          success: function (results) {
              model = results.d;
          },
          error: function (err) {
              alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
          }
      });

      vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
      ko.applyBindings(vm);
  });
  ```